# $post->post_type not working

Tags: posts, post-status

I have this simple piece of code that is not working:

```
    if ( 'publish' != $post->post_status ) {
    return;
}
```

When I use this in my code, it blocks posts that should have a status of 'publish'.

If I replace this with:

```
    if ( 'publish' != get_post_status( $post_id) ) {
    return;
}
```

It works, however this is working on the post status from the last save, not the current edit activity.

I've tried all sorts of combinations alternatives, but I still can't get it work. Any ideas what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you put this code? Are you sure that $post variable is set?

Comment: Ah I fixed this almost as soon as I posted the question. The problem was with my $post variable, I was not creating it properly. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `global $post;` above the `if ('publish...` statement?

Reference [https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/$post](http://Codex%20WordPress)

Comment: Yep this was missing, unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

The problem in my code was down to the $post variable, I'd not declared it properly, I added $post=get_post($post_id); to my code and all worked as expected.